# Using Chrome, why is PDF downloaded from one site but displayed with Chrome pdf viewer from another site?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, download, viewer

My company moved our shared files from one instance of Microsoft Sharepoint to another instance. Strangely, when I try to open a PDF in the new instance, Chrome downloads the PDF, while in the old instance of Sharepoint, Chrome displays the PDF in its built-in viewer. How can I make Chrome use its PDF viewer for documents in the new Sharepoint? I searched around and most questions on this site and others is about preventing the Chrome viewer. I want to ensure that it is always used.

Answer (score 4):

Is the new instance a newer version? Websites have some ability to direct how files they send should be handled, e.g. they can indicate that a file should be downloaded rather than viewed. I suspect that this has changed from version to version. It might be configurable, perhaps if you asked your sharepoint administrators they could look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Response headers for the resource you requested can have a great impact on how a browser treats the output.  The new version of sharepoint may simply be telling the browser to react differently.  Is the behavior similar on other browsers?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say with other browsers since I'm not aware of IE9 or Firefox 4 having a built-in viewer like Chrome.